# Simplifying a complex melody in Finale

Tags: software, instruments, finale

I'm arranging some music in Finale. It's written for professional instrumentalists, so many of the notes are fast. However, the underlying melody is less complex. Suppose I wanted to create a less-complex arrangement that follows the underlying melody. Is Finale capable of simplifying a complex melody? (Say, for instance, my target is to have notes no faster than 1/8 in the simple version that's derived from a version with lots of 1/16 notes and some 1/32 notes.) If so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Finale can't do it. YOU can do it, using Finale as your music-writing tool

Answer (score 3):

Basically, anything you can do, Finale can do.  If you understand music theory and composition well enough to reduce and simplify a melody yourself, then you can use Finale to help make that happen.  There is no known "auto-simplify" plugin for Finale.  Finale has a score reduction plugin that is laughable, but apart from that, the other plugins are primarily for what Finale humorously describes as "exploding" the music.

Figure out which notes are more important and delete the ones that are ornamentation.  If you've got a run of 16th notes that outline a C major scale, delete every other one, re-write as 8th notes and treat it like an arpeggio. To further simplify, use 1 note per beat and outline the upward motion with quarter notes, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked through the Finale 2014 included plugins and I don't see anything that does what you want.  If it's something you need to do 100's or 1000's of times then it might be worth exploring FinaleScript to try and automate the process.  Otherwise your best bet is to learn the speedy entry tool and modify the melody by hand.